# Find a sequence that makes the series satisfy the inequality below

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $0<a_n=o(\frac{1}{n}),0<b_n=O(n^2),$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2b_n$ converges, please help me find an unbounded increasing function $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb  R^+$ s.t.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2f(b_n)\leq C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2,$$

where $C$ is a constant that doesn't depend on $a_n,b_n$.

I come to this difficulty when I want to find a compact subspace by multiplying the basis vectors with eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, if that is not the case, it's trivial because the two sides are convergence

Comment: $f(x)=x$  is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=N\log(1+x)$ for $x>0$, where

$$N=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2b_n}.$$

Then $f:\mathbb R^+\!\!\to\!\mathbb R^+$ is unbounded and increasing. We also have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2f(b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2\left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2\log(1+b_n)}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2b_n}\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2,$$

where $\leq$ is due to $b_n>0$ and $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for $x>0$.

(Note that $f$ has to depend on both $a_n$ and $b_n$, otherwise $C$ will depend on $a_n$ or $b_n$.)